# Form submission in JQuery - why provide action parameter to form when using event handler

Tags: jquery, forms

I wrote following code to handle form submission in JQuery

```
$('#registration-form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var details = $('#registration-form').serialise();
    $.post('/newreg',details,function(data){});
});
```

I notice that the above code worked if I declare HTML form as follows:

```
<form id="registration-form" action="/newreg" method="post">
```

But doesn't work if I do not provide action and method in form tag

```
<form id="registration-form">
```

Haven't I already mentioned in JQuery the event handler, action and method for the form? Isn't it redundant to mention the same things again in HTML form tag?

Comment: Note: HTML4 specs require you to have action attribute set (to anything, but set)

Comment: I notice that spelling of serialize is incorrect in my code. It should be serialize, not serialise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Haven't I already mentioned in JQuery the event handler, action and method for the form?

You have, but you could read them with JavaScript and have a more generic function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    method: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { });
```

> Isn't it redundant to mention the same things again in HTML form tag?

Yes, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing.

See [the dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/redundant):

> Engineering (of a component) not strictly necessary to functioning but included in case of failure in another component.

If you are writing high quality, robust code, then having redundancy in the system is desirable. [Javascript does fail](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) so writing it in a way that is [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is best practise.

(The significant bit here is the the form being wired up correctly rather than the values being duplicated in the JS. See the top of the answer for how to avoid that duplication).

Comment: Thanks. And what can I do if I want to send data as JSON? Is this OK? `var details = JSON.stringify($('#registration-form').serialize());` I am facing some other problems so cannot really test if JSON.stringify would work at this time.

Comment: "And what can I do if I want to send data as JSON?" — Getting speaking: Stop wanting that. In *most* cases JSON brings no benefits, requires more work, and (since HTML forms can't generate JSON without JS) makes writing the code unobtrusively harder (since you need to parse the data in two different ways on the server).

Comment: " Is this OK? `var details = JSON.stringify($('#registration-form').serialize());`" — Technically speaking. That will send JSON. It will encode the data using the standard form encoding. Then it will encode that as JSON. This probably isn't what you want. How to approach collecting all the data in a form and expressing it as JSON is a whole other question.

Comment: "JSON brings no benefits" - I can think of HTML, XML or JSON as my options to send data. I expect that the clients of my web application could be browsers and apps. So keeping only HTML will not work. If I use JSON, I'll not have to worry about different types of data formats from different types of clients. Could you think of any other option?

Comment: @ManuChadha — A form in an HTML document will send data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format by default. It is trivial to encode data in that format in just about any language.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this ajax request code with out action or method declaration

```
    $('#registration-form').on('submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var details = $('#registration-form').serialise();
     $.ajax({
     url : '/newreg',
     data : details,
     type : 'post',
     function : success(data){
      console.log(data); 
     },
     function : error(data){
      console.log(data); 
     }
    });

    });
```

Comment: Why would that work if the OP's code didn't work? What is wrong with their original code?

Comment: @nnnnnn  OP's code in not define the url and method in $.post request

Comment: Yes it did, the URL is the first argument to `$.post()`, and the `$.post()` function itself obviously sets the method to `POST`...

Comment: ya but the code can run @nnnnnn i am always reuqest with this format

Comment: You've just rewritten the code (so it does the same thing with different functions) without answering the question at all.